# How to make dynamic search result page to index?

Tags: seo, google-search

Suppose i have an internal search engine that works on this parameters

```
foo.bar/search/?where=Rome&what=restaurant&categories=healthy
```

that i can dinamically alias to

```
foo.bar/restaurants/healthy-restaurants-in-rome
```

This uri will return dynamic results.

I want the friendly url to be indexed in google, but the alias will be dynamically generated only when some user will perform a search with the given parameters, and the aliased url will be **not** listed anywhere in my site.

Will google be able to crawl the alias? If yes, how? If not, what to do in order to get it indexed?

Comment: Don't have two URLs for your pages. That doesn't help anybody. Pick one format and stick with it.

Comment: What do you mean? Any mod_rewrite(d) site has at least 2 urls, the language native (index?foo=1&bar=2&baz=3) and the rewrited one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the alias pulls up a valid web page, Google will be able to crawl it. You just need to make that URL available to them, most likely though an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/) if the URL will not be available on your website.

The problem you're going to have is [duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en). You'll have two URLs pulling up the same content which is exactly what Google doesn't want to have in its index. If you create an alias for a page, and you want that URL to be the one Google shows in the search results, then you also have to edit the original page to add a [canonical URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en). Without it, you run into the duplicate content issues.

What you should be doing is creating the search engine friendly URL for every page immediately and only use that URL. That will make both users and search engines happy as they will only see one URL per page and it will read more naturally than a query string.